# How to reuse ssh connection during entire pytest suite

Tags: ssh, integration-testing, pytest, e2e-testing

I have an e2e test suite which loads some fixtures in in the database by calling a script on the server side using an SSH connection.

I want to keep the fixtures that i load local to test that needs them. I would write a test something like

```
class ExampleTests(BaseTest):
    def test_A(self):
        load_fixture('TEST_A')
        do_actual_test()

    def test_B(self):
        load_fixture('TEST_B')
        do_actual_test()
```

In my `load_fixture` method the SSH connection is made and the script is run on the server side.
If i run the entire test suite it will create a new SSH connection each time I call the `load_fixture` method. Conceptually this is what i want. I don't want to load all my fixtures for all my tests before any test runs. I want to be able to run fixtures when i need them. e.g.

```
class ExampleTests(BaseTest):
    def test_B(self):
        user_a = load_user_fixture('username-A')
        do_some_testing_on_user_a()
        load_post_fixture_for_user(user_a, subject='subject-a')
        do_tests_using_post()
```

In this test it would also create 2 ssh connections.

So what i want to have happen is that the first time i call the `load_fixture` method it creates the connection but keeps it around for the duration of the test suite. Or i create a connection before any test runs and then use that connection whenever i load a fixture.
Of course it should keep working when i run the tests over multiple core.

My `load_fixture` function looks something like:

```
def load_fixtures(connection_info, command, fixtures):
    out, err, exit_code = run_remote_fixture_script(connection_info, command, fixtures)

def run_remote_fixture_script(connection_info, command_name, *args):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.connect(...)
    command = '''
        ./load_fixture_script {test_target} {command} {args};
    '''.format(
        test_target=connection_info.target,
        command=command_name,
        args=''.join([" '{}'".format(arg) for arg in args])
    )
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    ssh.close()
    return stdout, stderr, exit_code
```

I also want to reopen the connection automatically if for any reason the connection closes.

Comment: Just for the record: I think the tag *unit test* is wrong here. Something that makes ssh calls is **not** a unit test. Most people think that "unit tests" run in **complete** isolation.

Comment: Thanks, i agree, i changed the tags

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`@pytest.fixture(scope="module")`

Keeping the scope as module will keep it for whole test suite.

and finalizer method within your fixture

```
`def run_remote_fixture_script(connection_info, command_name, *args):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.connect(...)
    command = '''
       ./load_fixture_script {test_target} {command} {args};
      '''.format(
    test_target=connection_info.target,
    command=command_name,
    args=''.join([" '{}'".format(arg) for arg in args])
)
   stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
   exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
   def fin():
     print ("teardown ssh")
     ssh.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
return stdout, stderr, exit_code
```

Please Excuse the formating of code. You could see this [link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) for more details

And you would call this fixture as

`def test_function(run_remote_fixture_script)
        output =  run_remote_fixture_script`

Hope this helps .
Finalizer method will be called end of test suite , if scope is method it will be called after method

Comment: You could use  " scope=session"  if you have multiple modules.